# slice up latex pdf to little jpeg's

Tags: equations, linux, pdfcrop, jpeg

**What I would like to achieve**

I would like to take **all** the equations in a pdf file and convert them to **individual** jpegs, is this possible, say by passing a compiler option?

- I specifically don't want to use any latex stuff on the web, I would like an automated workflow to handle an arbitrarily large number of equations/jpeg files
- I'm using emacs/linux so any command line tricks are fair game and desired
- currently I'm using [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) to manually do this. Even for a small number of equations this is troublesome, because the uniformity (bounding box around equation) is an issue

**Idea on how to achive this**

- possibly render each equation as it's own pdf using some TeX trickery, then using a tool like  [imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) convert to other formats
- [This workflow using pdfcropp and pdftoppm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible) seems like a start but doesn't crop each equation individually.

Thanks!

Comment: Please reconsider your choice of jpeg to display equations. I suggest to use .png instead.

Comment: have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134573/saving-tex-formulae-as-images, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287481/using-latex-to-generate-png-images-of-an-equation and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14974/exporting-all-equations-from-a-document-as-individual-svg-files

Comment: @samcarter Good links, also good are https://gist.github.com/ahwillia/ce9a842f122757518c65d0bd545f28c1#file-equations-tex-L2    and    https://github.com/johnjosephhorton/texscrap